# I'm trying to use SVG animate and animateTransform

Tags: svg

I'm trying to use SVG animate and animateTransform.
The animations is triggered using mouseover and mouseout.

The first example that I made, changes the object colors during mouseover and mouseout events and seems to work well.

In the second
I'm trying to change the rotation during mouseover and mouseout events
using:  fill="freeze" additive="sum".

But seems to work well only on the first mouseover, all the the next mouseover event fails in  strange way.

I tried many time by changing all the parameters but I think, maybe it's a SVG bug.

thanks for your help

this is the link

https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BwRlR3z6e0egY2RtWXZmVmU1Y0U/test_mouse_in_out.svg

This is the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="842px" height="595px" viewBox="0 0 842 595" enable-background="new 0 0 842 595" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 552.381 250.537)" stroke-width="1.4834077083798625" stroke-miterlimit="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#3D70B1" d="... ">
      <animateTransform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="mouseover" dur="1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" additive="sum" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1" values="0 50 25;180 50 25"/>
      <animateTransform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="mouseout" dur="2" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" additive="sum" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1" values="0 50 25;-180 50 25"/>
    </path>
    <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 150.733 232.565)"  stroke-width="1.0106517551310161" stroke-miterlimit="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#2128DF" d="...">
      <animate xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" begin="mouseover" dur="0.5" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" to="#FF0000"/>
      <animate xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" begin="mouseout" dur="0.5" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" to="#2128DF"/>
    </path>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're trying to achieve?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" x="0px" y="0px" width="842px" height="595px" viewBox="0 0 842 595" enable-background="new 0 0 842 595" xml:space="preserve" xmlns:xml="http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 552.3817663817669 250.5378939494907)" >
        <path width="100" height="193.24786324786277" stroke-width="1.4834077083798625" stroke-miterlimit="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#3D70B1" d="M49.17044074315265,-81.02222443382041 L100,0 L100,61.9415551961163 Q99.5833333333336,111.38520427855761 52.11894586894584,112.22563881404236 Q4.654558404558088,113.06607334952727 0,61.9415551961163 L0,0 L49.17044074315265,-81.02222443382041 Z ">
          <animateTransform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="mouseover" restart="whenNotActive" dur="1" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" additive="replace" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1" values="0 50 25;180 50 25"/>
          <animateTransform xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" begin="mouseout" dur="2" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" additive="sum" calcMode="spline" keySplines=".5 0 .5 1" values="0 50 25;-180 50 25"/>
        </path>
    </g>
    <path transform="matrix(1 0 0 1 150.73359748845195 232.56562387630248)" width="202.57122507122506" height="91.53846153846155" stroke-width="1.0106517551310161" stroke-miterlimit="3" stroke="#000000" fill="#2128DF" d="M182.57122507122506,0 Q202.57122507122506,0 202.57122507122506,20 L202.57122507122506,71.53846153846155 Q202.57122507122506,91.53846153846155 182.57122507122506,91.53846153846155 L20,91.53846153846155 Q0,91.53846153846155 0,71.53846153846155 L0,20 Q0,0 20,0 L182.57122507122506,0 Z ">
      <animate xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" begin="mouseover" dur="0.5" restart="whenNotActive" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" to="#FF0000"/>
      <animate xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" attributeName="fill" attributeType="CSS" begin="mouseout" dur="0.5" repeatCount="1" fill="freeze" to="#2128DF"/>
    </path>
</svg>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/longsonr/pmdqy/)

Comment: ops, no the mouseover and mouseout restart the animations from the begin and not from the current tranform.

Comment: I don't understand your second comment. I thought you wanted the animation to repeat as it did when the mouse enters and leaves the first time every time, on Firefox that's what happens. Maybe Chrome has a bug.

Comment: I want create a simple button that when the mouse go over it, rotates
but if I go out with mouse pointer comes back from the current rotation and not from the start of the animation.

like the interpolation color of the other object

Comment: I think you'll probably need scripting to do that as the animateTransform to return to 0 does not have a fixed duration or start point.

Comment: fortunatly I can make it with css.
thanks for your help.  https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BwRlR3z6e0egY2RtWXZmVmU1Y0U/test_mouse_over_css.svg

Comment: -webkit-transform: translate(100px, 50px) scale(2) rotate(30deg ) translate( -100px, -50px);
   
   -moz-transform: translate(100px, 50px) scale(2) rotate(30deg ) translate( -100px, -50px);

Comment: https://www.googledrive.com/host/0BwRlR3z6e0egY2RtWXZmVmU1Y0U/test_mouse_over_css.css